# JAXB How to parse empty value string to null Integer

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the next problem.
I have to define the attribute of XLS as Integer. When the XMLAdapter (define for me) receives the value, instead of receiving a null or empty, you receive a 0 (because de Integer parse emty '' value to 0), which is incorrect in my case. How do I know if this value comes from a "" or a 0? I need If the attribute value is "", the value should be Null; if 0, should be 0. For me it is a bug in JAXB.
I read:
[JAXB: how to make JAXB NOT to unmarshal empty string to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133250/jaxb-how-to-make-jaxb-not-to-unmarshal-empty-string-to-0/27254185#27254185)
But its not a solution for me.
What can I do?!
I defined mi XMLAdapter:

```
public class IntegerAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Integer, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer marshal(Integer arg0) throws Exception {
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer unmarshal(Integer v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }
}
```

I dont define it like `XmlAdapter<String, Integer>`, because the definition of the XLS attribute must be Integer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following instead:

```
XmlAdapter<String, Integer>
```

---

> I dont define it like `XmlAdapter<String, Integer>`, because the
>   definition of the XLS attribute must be Integer.

You can use the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation to set the schema type you want.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntegerAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name="integer")
public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code how it has been achieved actually i am not able to manage this.i am facing same problem with Long